# Changing double to character array in Android

Tags: android

I need to change a double into a character array.  In other words I have a variable that is a double and I would like to represent it as a character array.  I want to do this because I am using the USB port on my Nexus One as a serial port and the only way I can get it to work is to send characters and I have GPS data that I want to send out which are doubles.

Comment: First, you have asked 10 questions, 9 of which are answered, and you haven't accepted anything. You need to work on that. Second, do you want to send the characters in a decimal representation of the double, or do you want to send the bits as if they were characters?

Comment: What is "accept anything"?  I want to send it so that I can reconstruct it on the other side (on a PC).  What ever is easier would be best.

Comment: you must mark answers to your questions as the accepted answer so people get credit for helping you.

Comment: It means you should accept some of the answers to your previous questions if you found them useful. That way people are more likely to help you

Comment: @user758362 you might want to read about "How do I ask questions here?" in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You might also be interested in the next topic, "What is reputation?".

Comment: Good thank-you.  Actually most of the answers here have been very useful.

Comment: Ok.  I have done my duty.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: i suggest you change your username!! user758362 isn't a cool name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char[] characters = String.valueOf(myDoubleVariable).toCharArray();

Comment: That is one way.  I discovered another as I stated above:        String doubleString = Double.toString(double_number);             where double_number is a double and doubleString is a string and the string can be used like a character pretty much.